# Not able to upload image on real time database, working in fragments in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

```
public class statusFragment extends Fragment {
    //StatusfragmentBinding binding;
    TopStatusAdapter statusAdapter;
    ArrayList<UserStatus> userStatuses;
    ///we  are creating customize fragment where first layut is created then class creat to attach then to the activities by creating classes while in simple activities creation both layout and activity is created at same time
    ImageButton camerastatus;
    RecyclerView statusList;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    // for uploading
    FirebaseDatabase database;

    private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private static int PICK_IMAGE = 123;
    private Uri imagepath;
    private String ImageUriAcessToken;
userprofile user; //user obj
    @Nullable

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable  ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.statusfragment,container,false);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        dialog.setMessage("Uploading Image...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
      
        //like specific
        database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        userStatuses= new ArrayList<>();//need to remove from TopstatusAdapter


        statusList = view.findViewById(R.id.statusList);
        camerastatus= view.findViewById(R.id.camerastatus);
        statusAdapter= new TopStatusAdapter(getContext(),userStatuses);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
        statusList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        statusList.setAdapter(statusAdapter);
      
             StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("SImages").child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Status Pic");

       
        //before like video
        database.getReference().child("status").child(firebaseAuth.getUid())
.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                user = snapshot.getValue(userprofile.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
      
        camerastatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //before:

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 75);
             

            }

        });

        return view;
    }
  

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,@Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      
        if(data != null) {
            if(data.getData() != null) {
              
                //firebase to upload data
                FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                Date date = new Date();
              
                StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("SImages").child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Status Pic");
                reference.putFile(data.getData()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                            reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                               //dialog.dismiss();
                                    UserStatus userStatus = new UserStatus();
                                    userStatus.setName(user.getUsername());
                                   
                                    userStatus.setLastUpdated(date.getTime());
                                    HashMap<String,Object> obj=new HashMap<>();
                                    obj.put("name", userStatus.getName());
                                  
                                    obj.put("lastUpdated", userStatus.getLastUpdated());
                                    String imageUrl = uri.toString();
                                    Status status = new Status(imageUrl, userStatus.getLastUpdated());

                                   
                                    database.getReference().child("status").child("stories").updateChildren(obj);
                                   

                                    database.getReference().child("stories").child("status")
                                         .child("stories")
                                       .push()
                                      .setValue(status);

                                   

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });



            }
        }


    }

}[image1[\]\[1\]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eCEz.jpg
```

this is a status fragment , i want to make a module like WhatsApp status, here in the code above i am uploading the image on firebase storage that is working fine , image is being uploaded but in real-time database the image is not being uploaded.

I have attached the screenshot of my storage where data is being uploaded and also the screenshot of real time database where image is not being uploaded .

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `.setValue(status)` operation, to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?